# What do you call a mother whose children have died?

Tags: single-word-requests

For instance, a child whose parents have died is an orphan; while a woman whose husband has died is a widow...

Comment: From the answers given in the other question, I'm partial to the term "orphaner" (which would complement "orphan" in the same way that "widower" complements "widow"). But the short answer is there isn't a common term.

Comment: Also on ELL [...parents who lost their child](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/19571/a-parentless-child-is-an-orphan-but-the-parents-who-lost-their-child-are)